# all contents of jquery accordian to make uncollapsed

Tags: jquery

i am using jquery UI accordian from this site:

http://jqueryui.com/accordion

the problem is that i am not able to find an option where you can keep the content already opened, then when you  click on any tab, the content closes.

```
.ui-widget-content {display: block;}
```

when in tried to make the content class `display:block`, then even on clicking any tab, the content does not close. please help.

Answer (score 0):

That would not be an accordion any more, and jquery UI accordion does not support multiple sections open at once. However, this is trivial to code one such odd *accordion* as you could see in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/agoxat/1/edit).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#odd-accordion h4").click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery UI accordion don't have the option that you want, but why not a custom accordion:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/qd8yb/)**

**[ACCORDION FIDDLE WITH EASING PLUGIN](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/CZyjW/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
     <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>

    <div class="content">
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>
     <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>

    <div class="content">
        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.</p>
    </div>
     <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>

    <div class="content">
        <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>

    <div class="content">
        <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est.</p>
        <p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    background: #e3e3e0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
:focus, :active {
    outline: 0;
}
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#accordion {
    width: 500px;
}
#accordion .content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 16pt;
    font-family:arial;
}
#accordion .content > * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
#accordion .content a {
    color: #777;
}
#accordion h3 {
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 0px;
}
#accordion h3 a {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 42px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12pt;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:arial;
}
#accordion h3 {
    background-color: #389abe;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #389abe 0%, #2a7b99 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #389abe), color-stop(100%, #2a7b99));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #389abe 0%, #2a7b99 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #389abe 0%, #2a7b99 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #389abe 0%, #2a7b99 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #389abe 0%, #2a7b99 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#389abe', endColorstr='#2a7b99', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
#accordion h3 a {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);
}
#accordion .content {
    box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
#accordion .content:last-of-type {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), inset 0px 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {

    $('#accordion h3').click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return false;
    }).next().show();

})
```